# Running Vb-Script from R

Tags: r, excel, vba

I using this tutrial.

https://www.listendata.com/2016/07/run-vba-in-r.html

I know a little R but not VBA.

I have a question about the lines of code in step 1:

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Visible = True
objExcel.DisplayAlerts=False
Set wb = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Deepanshu\Documents\example.xlsx")
Set Xlsheet = wb.Worksheets("PRDSALE")
Xlsheet.UsedRange.Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
Xlsheet.UsedRange.Borders.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
Xlsheet.UsedRange.Borders.Weight = xlThick
wb.save
```

How can I make the code to save and close the excel file? 
Because now when I run those lines in r:

```
pathofvbscript = "C:\\Users\\Deepanshu\\Documents\\border.vbs"
shell(shQuote(normalizePath(pathofvbscript)), "cscript", flag = "//nologo")
```

The excel app is opening. If I close it the file will not be saved at all. I want that changes will be commited when the excel doesn't open at all - "Behind the Scenes". Any way?

Comment: To get a start on it, record a macro when performing the actions in Excel.

Comment: How can I record an action that closes Excel application?

Comment: You don't mention quitting excel, you mention saving and closing the excel file.

Comment: so how can quit excel by macro code?

Comment: @Jordan1200 `wb.close`

Comment: @Dorian, no that does not quit Excel, it only clsoes the workbook.

Comment: @CindyMeister Does **quit excel** means kill excel via shell ?

Comment: @Jordan, please [edit] the question to ask *exactly* what you need to do. Don't discuss and go back-and-forth in comments. What you ask, in the last paragraph, makes no sense. "Of course" the Excel application is opening - automation code can only run *in* the Excel application. If you want to do something with an Office file and *not* use the application, then you need to work with the Office Open XML file format - something entirely different.

Comment: In the context being discussed here (the COM object model) I assume the equivalent of File/Exit (or Quit) is meant. OTOH it's not at all clear what the OP really wants...

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the last step of your tuto : [VB Script : Run Excel Macro from R](https://www.listendata.com/2016/07/run-vba-in-r.html) , it will save workbook after macro's execution :

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application") 
objExcel.Visible = True
objExcel.DisplayAlerts=False
Set wb = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Deepanshu\Documents\Book1.xls")
objExcel.Application.Run "Book1.xls!macro1"
wb.save
```

where `Book1.xls!macro1` is `workbookName!MacroName`

Comment: But the excel sheet is an new excel that R outputs. I cannot insert a macro in automatically.

Comment: @Jordan1200 You can use `saveWorkbook(wbfullpath)` in R to save workbook, you just got to know the name and the path of the generated workbook also note that `wbfullpath <- loadWorkbook("testFile.xlsx", create = TRUE)`